# Toggling between 3 frequencies

Tags: verilog

I currently have a program that runs at X frequency, with the clock input generated by a slow clock module that divides the default clock via the counter increment method.

However, I wish to be able to switch between 3 frequencies, X, Y and Z using button presses. I have debounced the buttons with a single pulse signal generator module (using d flip flops). How can I go about doing it using rudimentary concepts only (multiplexer, etc)? Also, should the logic be implemented inside the slow clock module or in the main module?

Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe1qVv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Needs a diagram!

Comment: @FiddyOhm Tried to create a visualisation of what I have in mind. Basically I'm not sure how U3 should be coded such that the signal generated from U3 to main module is from either of the 3 divided clock signals. Especially because I'm using a button to toggle between the 3, not a switch.

Comment: Why not use a single programmable divider? Changing the programming should not produce any unwanted glitches at the output.

Comment: I assume each button press only cycles thru 3 states. f= X,Y,Z  ..repeat in one direction only rather than up/down. TO make it synchronous , glitch free, the transition must be sync'd with a D register using the input clock between U3 out and main module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with [verilog](/questions/tagged/verilog), I'll assume that you're really looking for an HDL solution targeted at an FPGA. In this case, using a single programmable divider makes a whole lot more sense than having multiple dividers followed by a multiplexer. Something like this:

```
module clockdiv (
  input         master_clock,
  input         reset,
  input   [1:0] select,
  output reg    clock_out
)

  reg    [15:0] divider;

  always @* begin
    case (select)
      2'b00: divider <= X; // defined elsewhere
      2'b01: divider <= Y; //
      2'b10: divider <= Z; //
      2'b11: divider <= W; // ... etc.
    endcase
  end

  reg    [15:0] counter;

  always @(posedge master_clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      counter <= 0;
      clock_out <= 0;
    end else begin
      if (counter >= divider) begin
        counter <= 0;
        clock_out <= !clock_out;
      end else begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Define `X`, `Y`, `Z`, etc. to give you the clock division ratios you're looking for, keeping in mind that the output clock is further divided by 2 to produce a square wave.

This solution will never produce a bad clock pulse, even if the `select` input changes in the middle of an output cycle.

---

Addressing your secondary problem of controlling the select lines, the key here is to bring the two debounced pushbutton signals into the same clock domain as the rest of the logic. Something like this:

```
module up_down (
  input            master_clock,
  input            reset,
  input            button_up,
  input            button_down,
  output reg [1:0] count
)

  // Synchronizers and edge detectors for asynchronous inputs
  reg              button_up_a, button_up_b, button_up_c;
  reg              button_down_a, button_down_b, button_down_c;

  always @(posedge master_clock) begin
    button_up_a <= button_up;
    button_up_b <= button_up_a;
    button_up_c <= button_up_b;

    button_down_a <= button_down;
    button_down_b <= button_down_a;
    button_down_c <= button_down_b;

    if (reset) begin
      count <= 0;
    end else begin
      if (button_up_b && !button_up_c) begin
        //rising edge on button_up detected
        count <= count + 1;
      end else if (button_down_b && !button_down_c) begin
        //rising edge on button_down detected
        count <= count - 1;
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Connect the `count` output of this module to the `select` input of the previous module.

Comment: Thank you! I follow your rationale of localizing the clock divisions. I have one small question however. For the 2-bit select variable, I'm supposed to toggle it with buttons (say btnLeft, btnRight) to decrease and increase the value by 1. I have coded a module to debounce the signal from the button, but have yet to find a way to make it work with the board. I tried something like... `always @ (posedge btnLeft) begin SELECT <= SELECT - 1 end` , but I can't include SELECT in more than one always @ block so I can't write another `always @ (posedge btnRight) begin SELECT <= SELECT + 1`

Comment: The key is to not treat each button as a separate clock, but rather to bring them into the `master_clock` domain. See my edit above.

Comment: I see, that makes alot of sense, I've learnt alot from you Dave. However, may I know the rationale of propagating the button signal thrice instead of twice only and then using `button_up_a && !button_up_b`as the condition?

Answer (score -1):

In real-world terms your U3 would be a device called a "Data Selector" or "Multiplexer". Look into standard 7400 Logic Family devices like the 74ACT150, 74ACT151,74ACT152, or 74ACT153. These are generic devices that are available in several of the 7400 series families such as HC, HCT, AC, LS, F, etc. E.g. 74HC150 and 74HCT150 are logically equivalent, but their electrical input and output characteristics are different.

Data Selectors have "data select" inputs which you set to a Logic 0 or 1 in various combinations to select the input you want to appear on your output. In your case you could connect a pushbutton switch to each of these to select which of the three frequencies you want to direct to the output of U3. With a little more work you can connect the "data select" inputs to the outputs of a counter IC. E.g. a 74HC93. Then use the pushbutton switch to drive this counter IC. As you cycle the pushbutton the 7493 least significant bit outputs will follow the pattern of a binary count (00,01,10,11,00,01,10,00). These patterns will drive the Data Selector to its different input-to-output selection states.

Get the data sheets for these 7400 series ICs from DigiKey, etc and study them. You will find the concepts involved are quite simple.

Comment: Unless you take care to synchronize the select inputs with the respective clocks, this will likely produce unwanted glitches at the output.

Comment: Dave Tweed: And a number of other annoying characteristics. My answer wasn't intended as a detailed design. Rather, to give a rough topology.

Comment: To what end? The question already contains the rough topology, and it's asking for a Verilog solution anyway, not TTL.

Comment: Dave Tweed: I started my answer with "in real world terms....". The OP didn't explicitly say he wanted a Verilog solution.

Comment: The [tag:verilog] tag is a pretty strong clue.